# $p^q=q^p$ for $p, q\in\mathbb Q$

Tags: number-theory

Just saw a neat trick (the fact that $2^4=4^2$ 'saved the bacon' in the proof here: [How do I compare $\sqrt{2}$ and $\pi^{1/ \pi}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2551963/491874)). That led me to ask:

*What is known about pairs of positive rational numbers $p,q\in\mathbb Q$, $p, q>0$ such that $p^q=q^p$?*

For instance, is $p=2, q=4$ the only nontrivial ($p\ne q$) solution?

Comment: No, there are in fact infinitely many solutions with $p\neq q$ and both of them rational.

Comment: See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2147486/11619) and the ones linked to it. [Ross Millikan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2147518/11619) is relevant to your question. If $a/(a-1)$ is an integer then we have $x^y=y^x$ for $y=a^{a/(a-1)}, x=y/a$. Observe that here both $x$ and $y$ are then rational. The case $a/(a-1)=2$ gives $y=4, x=2$. When $a/(a-1)=4$ we get $a=4/3$, $y=256/81$ and $x=64/27$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do you happen to know if those are the only ones?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: E.g.: $\,p:=(1+1/t)^t\,$ and $\,q:=(1+1/t)^{t+1}\,$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9515/11619) for more.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen all solutions, proved, in Bennett Reznick http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/monthly013-021.pdf    formula (6)

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy

Answer (score 2):

Just to document the answer that **@WillJagy** gave in the comments:

> "all solutions, proved, in Bennett Reznick http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/monthly013-021.pdf, formula (6)".

which is:

$$x_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n, \qquad y_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$